# getting common numbers in each string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I have this list below. I am doing an ip calculator and am currently doing supernetting. I currently have the ip's as binary in a list.

I want to get the common numbers in a list and add them to a new variable so that I'll have a new string with all the common ones etc like it should stop adding the common numbers to a string when the same index's of each binary number stop being the same. I can't figure out how to compare each one though? I tried for loops and everything and it doesn't behave as I want it to.

```
['11001101011001000000000000000000', 
 '11001101011001000000000100000000', 
 '11001101011001000000001000000000', 
 '11001101011001000000001100000000']
```

my output for this should be `11001101 . 01100100 . 000000`

Comment: In other words, you want the longest common prefix of all the strings?

Comment: @tobias_k     yeah like in each string in the list, they all have the first 1 in common, second one in common and so on. But i can't figure out how to iterate through each string in the list

Comment: How did you derive to expected output ? would you mind to provide example for one ?

Comment: @Shakeel what do you mean? It was in some of my class notes on how to supernet in networks so I converted the ip addresses to binary and am now trying to get the common numbers in both

Comment: @coder125 Never mind I understood from tobias_k's explanation "longest common prefix of all the strings".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the longest common prefix of all the strings. There are probably more elegant and/or faster ways, but you could e.g. just `zip` the different strings and [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) they are all the same, i.e. have only one element as a `set`.

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> lst = ['11001101011001000000000000000000', 
...        '11001101011001000000000100000000', 
...        '11001101011001000000001000000000', 
...        '11001101011001000000001100000000']
...
>>> ''.join(t[0] for t in takewhile(lambda t: len(set(t)) == 1, zip(*lst)))
'1100110101100100000000'
>>> '.'.join(_[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(_), 8)) # just adding dots...
'11001101.01100100.000000'
```

Breaking this down a bit:

- `zip(*lst)` iterates the "slices" through all the strings in the list, e.g. `('1', '1', '1', '1')` for the first position
- `takewhile` takes that sequence and -- as the name suggests -- takes elements as long as the given condition is true
- `lambda t: len(set(t)) == 1` is that condition, converting the slice through the strings to a `set` and checking whether that set has just one element; for `('0', '0', '1', '1')`, the `set` will be `{'0', '1'}` and thus `takewhile` stops
- `''.join(t[0] for ...)` joins the same elements back to a string; here, `t[0]` is just the first element of the tuple of same elements
- the last line is just to add the `.` after 8 digits; here, `_` is the result of the previous line

Comment: thanks so much! :) so take while gets all the common numbers in each string? and what exactly does zip do here? Sorry haven't used both of these functions before